# Flag in one category blocks others

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

Raising a flag that a question should be closed *because it's off-topic* (or any reason other than *duplicate*) also marks as flagged the option that a question should be closed *because it's a duplicate*.  This is unexpected behavior because the user has not actually raised the "it's a duplicate" kind of flag.

I understand the technical background for why this displays (user has already raised a flag requesting closure) but what's shown to the user is factually incorrect from the user perspective, hence why I'm tagging this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) instead of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Screenshot from EL&U:

[image]

A closely related question has been asked on UX.SE [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88866/best-way-to-handle-when-typology-used-by-tech-is-different-than-typology-present), for additional expert perspectives that may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The message is not inaccurate. The standard "should be closed" and "duplicate" flag reasons are both the same *type* of flag - flags to close. You can only flag to close a question once, so both options get disabled once you've already cast one.

Comment: The user interface shows five options that appear to be the five different types of flags.  This may be a bug in UI design instead.

Comment: The UI design explicitly pulls the duplicate option out of the close menu because we 1) want to encourage flagging duplicates and 2) want to make it easier to do so. The current design is very much intentional. As an aside, if you flag as either spam or rude/abusive, both options will get disabled in that case as well. Each option is a different *reason*, not a different type.

Comment: Then I would suggest "this type of flag" be changed to something more specific that indicates what type of flag is being referred to, because the typology used by the technology is quite different than the one presented to the user.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for words that might be less confusing there?

Comment: I would want to know more about what the flags mean and are called in the code (as a first suggestion), but would "a spam/abuse flag" and "a close request flag" and "a moderator intervention flag" be fitting?  Are the first two also, in effect, close flags?  If so, what distinguishes them from the second two, that the effect does not cross over?  The answer to that might contain/suggest appropriate language.

Comment: The first two are just severe flags - they cause automatic downvotes and the user can lose 100 reputation if they get validated. Generally, if you use one, there's absolutely no reason you'd need to use the other in the future. Also note: there is no limit to the number of "other" flags you can cast on a single post, as we don't want users to reach a point where they literally can't flag the post at all (just in case). I'll see if it's easy to indicate "recommend closure flag" in the sentence as part of other updates we're making to the flag dialog right now.

Comment: So once a spam/rude/abusive flag is raised, are the first four options all grayed out?  If not, why not?  If it's just for UX purposes, why did that idea not extend to the UX issue that is unexpected to the user, described in this question?

Comment: No, raising a spam/rude flag will disable both spam/rude options. Raising a recommend closure flag will disable both the close options. They're independent of each other, because they're different types of flags.

Comment: It's not obvious to a typical user why the first two should be the same as each other and different from the other two which are also the same as each other.  Thus, the present behavior is unexpected.

Comment: It's not really a matter of what the user expects to happen - that's a really bad argument here. There are *tons and tons* of things that happen all over the Internet that can be argued as "the user didn't expect that to happen." You could argue that a user shouldn't expect any option to get disabled after they flag - that we should tell them "these options can't be used again after you flag" before they submit - but that's kind of a waste of time. Users can just flag and then find out they can only use the flag once. If the wording explaining that is confusing, that's what we should fix.

Comment: "There are tons and tons of things that happen all over the Internet that" ...are bad UI/UX design, I agree.  
"If the wording explaining that is confusing, that's what we should fix." Sounds like a good approach to me.

Comment: Wait, when did it become one flag per type? Wasn't it one standard + one custom not too long ago?